# How to force the tcolorbox package to cover the upper and lower part of pages?

Tags: framed, tcolorbox

The code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo bar}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[size=tight,oversize,
  sharp corners,
    breakable,
  enhanced,
  interior style={top color=green!30!white,bottom color=green!30!white},
  colframe=blue,
  colupper=black,
  left=170pt,
  right=170pt,
  bottom=10pt,
  top=10pt,
  ]
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

gives me this result:

[image]

but I want this result (it's Photoshop!):

[image]
**Is there a way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `underlay` options combined with `remember` and `frame hidden`. 
`remember` allows to make reference to other frame pictures or use `current page` node in `overlay|underlay` additions. `frame hidden` avoid spurious lines behind your filled rectangles.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo bar}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[oversize,
  remember,
  sharp corners,
    breakable,
  enhanced,
  frame hidden,
  underlay first={\fill[green!30!white] (frame.north-|current page.west) rectangle (current page.south east);},
  underlay last={\fill[green!30!white] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.east|-frame.south);},
  colframe=blue,
  colupper=black,
  bottom=10pt,
  top=10pt,
]
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: How to preserve header?**

I don't know how to solve this problem. To my understanding you want that something which is drawn later (colored box) doesn't cover something which is already printed on your page (header). It's possible that `tcolorbox` leaves some information about a broken box which could be used to know that some background must be added to next page before the header is printed. But I don't know how to use it. May be follow up question attracts interest of more smart brains than mine.

The best I can do, which looks horrible, is making a hole for header area with `tikzpagenodes` package help.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo bar}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[oversize,
  remember,
  sharp corners,
    breakable,
  enhanced,
  frame hidden,
  interior hidden,
  underlay first={\fill[green!30!white] (frame.north-|current page.west) 
                     rectangle (current page.south east);},
  underlay last={\begin{scope}[even odd rule, fill=green!30!white]
         \fill[clip] (current page.north west) rectangle 
                     (current page.east|-frame.south) 
                     (current page header area.north west) rectangle 
                     (current page header area.south east);
         \end{scope}
},
  colframe=blue,
  colupper=black,
  bottom=10pt,
  top=10pt,
]
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the header is gone! How can I bring it back?

Comment: @Sisabe I've updated the answer, but with a horrible solution. I think you'll need better help than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here  a solution for breakable box with two parts (first and last), you can use `overlay first` and `overlay last` to add graphical code for each part

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo bar}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[size=tight,oversize,
  sharp corners,
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  interior style={top color=green!30!white,bottom color=green!30!white},
  colframe=blue,
  colupper=black,
  left=170pt,
  right=170pt,
  bottom=10pt,
  top=10pt,
  remember,
  overlay first={\fill[green!30!white]
(frame.south east) rectangle (current page.south west)
;},
overlay last={
\fill[green!30!white]
(frame.north west) rectangle (current page.north east)
;}
  ]

\lipsum[2-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**Update**

You can show the header with `opacity` key and increase the color degree

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{size=tight,oversize,
  sharp corners,
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  interior style={color=green!30!white},
  colframe=blue,
  colupper=black,
  left=170pt,
  right=170pt,
  bottom=10pt,
  top=10pt,
  remember,
  overlay first={\fill[green!30!white]
(frame.south east) rectangle (current page.south west)
;},
overlay last={
\fill[green,opacity=0.3]
([yshift=0.5pt]frame.north west) rectangle (current page.north east)
;
}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo bar}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{mybox}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the header is gone! How can I bring it back?

Comment: Although `opactiy` let us see header, it's still covered. Compare it with footer in previous page.

Comment: @lgnasi This is the best of what I could get it.

Comment: Or you can redefine header after the tclorbox?

Comment: @salimbou: How to define the header after the tcolorbox?

Comment: @ThomasF. Sturm can have an appropriate solution to this problematic